# Want to manipulate and visualize differential equation of a falling object

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying to get ahead of my upcoming semester by visualizing a differential equation of a general ODE solution for falling objects with the given solution of

$$m\frac{{dv}}{{dt}} = mg - \gamma v
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamyBamaala
% aabaGaamizaiaadAhaaeaacaWGKbGaamiDaaaacqGH9aqpcaWGTbGa
% am4zaiabgkHiTiabeo7aNjaadAhaaaa!4131!
$$

where the solution is

$$v = (\frac{{mg}}{\gamma }) + [vo - (\frac{{mg}}{\gamma })]{e^{ - \frac{{\gamma t}}{m}}}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamODaiabg2
% da9iaacIcadaWcaaqaaiaad2gacaWGNbaabaGaeq4SdCgaaiaacMca
% cqGHRaWkcaGGBbGaamODaiaad+gacqGHsislcaGGOaWaaSaaaeaaca
% WGTbGaam4zaaqaaiabeo7aNbaacaGGPaGaaiyxaiaadwgadaahaaWc
% beqaaiabgkHiTmaalaaabaGaeq4SdCMaamiDaaqaaiaad2gaaaaaaa
% aa!4CF7!
$$

Where m=mass, g=gravity constant, γ=drag coefficient, v0 is the initial condition, t=time (and is the independent variable)

I would like to create a manipulate and see how different figures for mass, drag, time, vo (maybe?) change the graph or see how the graphs geometrically converge/diverage toward equilibrium solution which is mg/γ but I am not having much success with the manipulate command.

I would appreciate any assistance; I am still getting used to Mathematica.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post the code you’ve attempted for us so we may better help? Also, welcome to mma.SE!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something to get you started. Set the initial height at 100 above the ground. Plot shows how the object height changes

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 data = Table[{i, 
    sol /. {m -> theMass, drag -> theDrag, v0 -> theV0, t -> i}}, {i,0, time, 0.01}];
 ListLinePlot[data, AxesOrigin -> {0, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 200}}, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "y(t)"}, 
  BaseStyle -> 14, PlotStyle -> Red, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
 ,
 {{theMass, 10, "Mass"}, 0.01, 10, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{theDrag, 1, "Drag"}, 0.01, 10, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{theV0, 20, "Initial velocity"}, 0, 40, 0.01, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{time, 0.001, "time"}, 0.001, 10, 0.001, Appearance -> "Labeled"},

 TrackedSymbols :> {theMass, theDrag, theV0, time},

 Initialization :> {
   g = -9.81;
   ode = m y''[t] == m g - drag y'[t];
   sol = y[t] /. First@DSolve[{ode, y[0] == 100, y'[0] == v0}, y[t], t]
   }
 ]
```

Comment: Thankyou so much this will definately be a nice start to my ODE studies and help me with a working example as a reference for other mathematical models!

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot going on in this, especially for a new user, but computers and software seem to have convinced people that they need to build and see things like this and more.

```
Manipulate[
  sol=v/.DSolve[{m v'[t]==m g-gamma v[t],v[0]==v0},v,t][[1]];
  Plot[sol[t],{t,0,6}],
  {{m,1},0,2},{{g,32},16,64},{{gamma,0},0,1},{{v0,0},-12,12}]
```

Study the documentation for every part of this and see if you can understand what was the thinking that put this together. You can search for `Manipulate` and `DSolve` in the help system and study the examples to see if you can learn how this works. Sometimes clicking on the orange "Details" can provide you with additional information about using a function. You can even search for `/.` and `[[` and `==` and `=` to try to understand how each part of this works.

Comment: Thankyou. I wanted to upvote you but I don't have as much rep here as I do on the Math stack exchange. haha. I appreciate your insight. I will look into these things.

Comment: "seem to have convinced people that they need to build and see things like this and more" - what ever happened to treating people nicely? Is there any reason HappyHiggs shouldn't *want* to see & understand things like this? Is it only for a select few, maybe?

Comment: @Paul_A I think you misunderstood my intent. I was not trying to mistreat him. His response to me didn't seem like he thought I was trying to mistreat him. I was trying to convey that again and again I see new users making their task far harder by thinking that they just must add layer after layer after layer of difficulties trying to figure out how to use animation and things like that, when sometimes they don't even know enough to be able to correctly solve a differential equation and produce a simple plot, let alone all the problems they face when they think they need to animate everything

Answer (score 0):

HappyHiggs - there are some good answers above - hope you got what you were looking for. Be aware that drag-coefficient depends on fluid viscosity, density, shape & density/weight of the falling object.

The equations you started with work just as well with Cd being a function of the Reynolds number (D x v x Density/viscosity.

This infographic tells a whole lot. NASA has published correlations based on many measurements. https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/shaped.html